# Why Gradle Is Not Listed as a Project Option in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a new project in intellij, however i don't see Gradle as an option in create a new project wizard. Any ideas on how on how to enable?

[image: Create A New Project intellij]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle plug-in is probably disabled. Enable it back in Settings | Plugins.

If it doesn't help, delete the [third-party plug-ins directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) while IDE is not running.

Comment: Gradle-java plugin was disabled, Thanks